# Regression model for categorical DV with more than 2 response options

Tags: regression, categorical-data, model

I am soon going to start running a simple behavioral experiment where each response will be coded as belonging to one of 3 categories (or otherwise, as NA). I ran a similar experiment before, where the categorical responses fell into either the category 'Correct' or 'Incorrect' so we had coded them as 1 and 0, respectively, and we had fitted a logistic regression model with binomial distribution.

I don't quite know, however, what kind of a regression model would be appropriate in cases where there is more than 2 different response options, and they are not ordered on a scale.

I know this is probably a very basic question, but I am still in the process of learning.

Thank you for your patience,
Freya

Comment: Would multinomial logistic regression work for you?

Comment: Yes, I have Googled its properties, and it seems like what I need to do! Thanks so much!